On linux, can I implement my own TCP stack while interoperating with other processes on same host?
I'm aware of two main ways to write and receive network packets from an existing network interface on linux. The first is with the classic sockets API, in which the linux kernel is responsible for managing all the TCP/IP encapsulation for the data I send and receive. The second is with the AF_PACKET interface, in which I read and write raw IP (or even ethernet) packets to an interface. I'm setting aside TAP/TUN devices, veth pairs, bridges, and so forth, because in my use case I cannot create any new network interfaces, only work with existing ones.
With the AF_PACKET approach, if I want to both send and receive data and participate in a "real" TCP connection, it seems that I have to more or less take over control of the whole interface, because if I write, say, a SYN packet, and receive a SYNACK packet in response arrives, then even if I process the SYNACK packet via decoding packets on my AF_PACKET socket, the linux kernel will also process the SYNACK packet, possibly responding in some way or even routing it to an existing sockets API-level connecting.
What I'm wondering is: if I implement my own TCP stack, is there any way that I can communicate via ports on my linux kernel host interface, while allowing other processes to still use the ordinary sockets API on the same host interface? What I would like to say to the linux kernel is: "hey, please give me a TCP port that you're not using, and from now on please ignore packets to/from that port if you receive them", then I use my AF_PACKET socket to write TCP traffic using this allocated port.
Now, I could of course just write an nftables rule that drop TCP traffic to a certain port. The trouble with this is: how do I find a port that is not in use by any other process, and how do I reliably clean up the rule when my process exits? I have found that nftables rules are difficult to set up in a way that works reliably on hosts that already have complex nftables setups, and interoperate with services like docker that install their own nftables rules.

Seems more like an SO question...

You can also use raw sockets instead of AF_PACKET, those might perform better than AF_PACKET.

I think this is exactly what tun/tap devices are for; these are virtual network devices that are controlled by an application. tap devices are layer 2 (so you can implement non-IP protocols), tun devices are layer 3.
So:

Create the device

Configure the interface using ip link/ip addr etc so that you can pass traffic to it. E.g:
ip addr add 192.168.43.1/24 dev tun0
ip link set tun0 up


Direct traffic to addresses on the 192.168.43.0/24 network:
nc 192.168.43.10 100


Your application will read data from the file descriptor you received in the first step and can write data back as well.


Here's example code that creates a tun interface, reads data from it, and hexdumps it on stdout:
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int tun_alloc(char *dev) {
  struct ifreq ifr;
  int fd, err;

  if ((fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to open /dev/net/tun: %d: %s\n", fd,
            strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }

  memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));

  /* Flags: IFF_TUN   - TUN device (no Ethernet headers)
   *        IFF_TAP   - TAP device
   *
   *        IFF_NO_PI - Do not provide packet information
   */
  ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN;
  if (*dev)
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);

  if ((err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *)&ifr)) < 0) {
    close(fd);
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to acquire interface: %d: %s\n", fd,
            strerror(errno));
    return err;
  }
  strcpy(dev, ifr.ifr_name);
  return fd;
}

// via https://gist.github.com/ccbrown/9722406
void hexdump(const void *data, size_t size) {
  char ascii[17];
  size_t i, j;
  ascii[16] = '\0';
  for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    printf("%02X ", ((unsigned char *)data)[i]);
    if (((unsigned char *)data)[i] >= ' ' &&
        ((unsigned char *)data)[i] <= '~') {
      ascii[i % 16] = ((unsigned char *)data)[i];
    } else {
      ascii[i % 16] = '.';
    }
    if ((i + 1) % 8 == 0 || i + 1 == size) {
      printf(" ");
      if ((i + 1) % 16 == 0) {
        printf("|  %s \n", ascii);
      } else if (i + 1 == size) {
        ascii[(i + 1) % 16] = '\0';
        if ((i + 1) % 16 <= 8) {
          printf(" ");
        }
        for (j = (i + 1) % 16; j < 16; ++j) {
          printf("   ");
        }
        printf("|  %s \n", ascii);
      }
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  char name[IFNAMSIZ + 1], cmd[1024];
  int fd;

  fd = tun_alloc(name);
  if (fd < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "tunnel allocation failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "got interface: %s\n", name);
  snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "ip addr add 192.168.43.1/24 dev %s", name);
  if (system(cmd) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to configure interface\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "ip link set %s up", name);
  if (system(cmd) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to configure interface\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  while (1) {
    char buf[8192];
    int nb;

    nb = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (nb == 0) {
      break;
    } else if (nb < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "read failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(1);
    }

    printf("read %d bytes\n", nb);
    hexdump(buf, nb);
  }

  return 0;
}

If we run that (note that you must run this as root) and try to connect to address 192.168.43.10:
nc 192.168.43.10 100

We see as output:
read 64 bytes
00 00 08 00 45 00 00 3C  7B B8 40 00 40 06 E7 A7  |  ....E..<{.@.@...
C0 A8 2B 01 C0 A8 2B 0A  E5 28 00 64 7C 20 6C 3D  |  ..+...+..(.d| l=
00 00 00 00 A0 02 FA F0  82 47 00 00 02 04 05 B4  |  .........G......
04 02 08 0A C6 5E 5F 22  00 00 00 00 01 03 03 07  |  .....^_"........

From the documentation, that's two bytes of flags, two bytes of protocol information, and then the raw protocol data. So stripping off the tun device header, we have:
4500 003c 7bb8 4000 4006 e7a7 c0a8 2b01  E..<{.@.@.....+.
c0a8 2b0a e528 0064 7c20 6c3d 0000 0000  ..+..(.d| l=....
a002 faf0 8247 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  .....G..........
c65e 5f22 0000 0000 0103 0307            .^_"........

Which is a standard IPv4 packet. We could have our application decode this and generate an appropriate response.
Notes:

You will probably see other output as well, since most systems perform a variety of network service announcement/discovery over all available interfaces.
If you don't want the initial packet metadata (the flags and protocol information), then you can set IFF_NO_PI when making the TUNSETIFF ioctl; in this case, you will receive only the raw IP data.

